# My mirror modifier doesn't mirror on x axis and rotation shows 0°, I applied rotation already

Tags: mirror, origin

Hello i have a problem with my miirror midifier it currently looks like this:

[image]

I don't know what's the problem on google it says that i have to applyrotation but i already did and doesn't fix this. You can see my rotation is all set to 0. I tried closing and opening blender thought it's a bug or something but it still doesn't apply the correct mirror.

I already did press SHIFT + S and set the cursor to the middle of the grid and then SHIFT + CTRL+ALT+C to change origin to cursor then mirror and it doesn't help.

What else can i do to fix this please? Thank you.

Comment: Try applying location. Your location values look way to high for where your object is placed.

Answer (score 1):

Delete Mod, In object mode/ on the menu bar under Object/Apply (or Ctrl+A) apply Rotate and Scale. reapply mod